# start-stop-daemon error write to disk (some text)

Tags: c++, ofstream, start-stop-daemon

Have C++ server program that writes logs to disk.
Starting it from php script

```
shell_exec("start-stop-daemon -Sbvx /home/my_server.out");
```

inside this program:

```
ofstream log_file("/home/log.txt");
log_file << "some_log\n";
```

But there is no any log when start it as daemon :(
(when usual start ./my_server.out all works fine)

Answer (score 0):

fogot close file. log_file.close(); Thats why it does not works in daemon mode. (No auto close file when daemon killed)